# Node JS - Recursive Calls

Tags: node.js

So, I have a app that process files from a directory, I want the app to keep looking at the directory for new files and if found it will process it, so basically what i did was call the main function again when the file is not available, which will keep my app running, but i get the error

Error
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Here is a snippet of my code`enter code here

```
 function main(){
        const names = scan_dir();
        if(names.length <= 0){
            console.log("nothing found in stage directory");
            main();
            return;
        }else{
            console.log(names.length.toString(), "files found");
        }
// Do something
}

    function scan_dir(){
        const names = fs.readdirSync(STAGE_PATH)`enter code here`;
        return names.filter(name => {
            const abs_name = path.join(STAGE_PATH, name);
            const stats = fs.statSync(abs_name);
            return stats.isFile();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that whenever it fails to find it calls the function again, you're going to get a massive stack overflow error from this. You could just stick this in a loop and do it iteratively, that'll prevent it from getting this error.

```
search = true
while(search){
    names = scan_dir();
    if(names.length <= 0){
       console.log("nothing found in stage directory");
    }else{
       console.log(names.length.toString(), "files found");
       search = false;
    }
}`
```

Comment: Thanks that helped, Now i am running into another issue. Now when i new file in the stage folder . I get the Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, open